# Gaps in FASTA formatted genome?

Tags: molecular-genetics

I'm just getting interested in genetic structure and I decided to find a FASTA formatted genome (human) and I found one [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/568815594?report=fasta&from=73401680&to=73423985). However, I'm confused. I know that A can only match up to T and C to G but it appears as though T is matching up to T, A to A, C to A, and etc. How is this possible? Can there be gaps where T,A ,C ,or G is connected to nothing? Small part of genome: `ATTTAGAAATGACTAACAATTATGTAGGTTTATTTCTCTCAGTATAGAATGTTCATATAGAATT`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is based on a misunderstanding. You have a single strand, lets assume it's the red sequence in the image. The linear sequence along this strand is not limited by base-pairing rules.

The base-pairing rules (A-T, G-C) apply to the complimentary strand, given in blue in the image.

[image]
It's convention to only give the sequence for one strand because the base-pairing rules allow us to infer the complimentary sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, then you are referring to the base pairing of the genome. Here you have been misled as to how base pairing is presented. `ATTT` does not refer to a base pair between A,T and T,T but rather the sequence of letters in the [sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_strand) strand of the human genome. What you see here are more [stacking interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacking_(chemistry)) than base pairing between bases. Whenever navigating databases please remember that whatever genome you are viewing, you will always be presented with the sense strand of that genome. To get the base paired strand or anti-sense strand of that particular genome, you need to a reverse complement that particular sequence of letters.